# I created a new local repository and can't push to Github because git think my commit doesn't have any files (ls-files show files)

Tags: git, github

I wanted to make a new website using Hugo + Netlify, a CI/CD provider for static websites. I already had one site with all the contents, so I cloned - **not with git clone** - the `website` folder I have to another part of my computer. I then followed:

```
git init
git add -all
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin [link here.git]
git push
```

Nothing happened in the repository on GitHub. I'm using VSCode, so I tried to make a "empty" commit there. Nothing happened too.

I tried googling a bit but nothing seems related to my particular issue or I'm just bad at google-fu.

Comment: I should mention that I am, in my terminal at least, in the `website` folder. Did I git init in the folder before `website` by accident? How can I see it?

Comment: You are showing us what you said but not what Git said in reply. Git replies are meaningful and important. Show them too. For example, your `git push` command is possibly wrong and I would expect Git to say so.

Comment: @matt I solved this issue, but thank you for telling me this. I was also scolded my friends for not doing this. I'm keep that in mind in my future questions here. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cloned - not with git clone

Do you mean you simply copied it? Then it is still holding the old Git repo and your `git init` doesn't mean what you think it does. You need to start by cleaning out the repo:

```
rm -rf .git
```

Now when you say `git init` you will get a fresh repo.

Comment: See my answer. It was a different thing, but would it solve my problem in the same way?

Comment: My point stands. You seem to think that your `git init` created a new repo. It didn't. You still have, in this new folder, the old repo from the old website folder. In other words the problem was caused by the way you copied the first folder. No other answer points that out. Try doing what I said.

Comment: My friends explained why more since I didn't get your comment at first. Since I copied the .git from the original folder, I was still with all the 'git information" as well. So for example, the commit history of the original history shows up on the new repository. I get your point now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. From what I know we don't have `git add -all`, it's `--all` or `-A`. (v2.28+, update your git to 2.32)
2. You can see your current directories git status by `$ git status`.
   If it shows `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`, it's not initialized.
3. You're not showing any git messages, they're important mention them in your question with details, not what commands you entered but the answers those commands returned.

But this is what I'd do if I needed to make my project up into github, you need to create an empty repo first, then follow these commands, last but not least, you'll need to type your username/password on github and done:

```sh
$ git init
$ git add -A .
$ git commit -m "my first commit"
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repo.git
$ git branch -M main
$ git push
```

Follow [these instructions from github](https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line) for full information.

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried Mahdy Mirzade's answer and it failed. My friends suggested to `git remote -v`. The origin branch was redirecting to a different repository I own. Since the contents were identical between those two folders I created, git didn't notice any changes (That's how git works, right?) and VSCode wouldn't mention any changes on the files.

After `git remote -v`, I did the following:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add [correct repository link]
git add -A
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git push
```

and it worked.

Sorry for anything!